# Unity Animation is not playing after i animated material, also animator gets disabled when i play animation clip

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

Here have a look at this screen recording (https://youtu.be/PvAt_t0NdQk). What am I doing wrong? I have selected prefab and working on it directly. I animated the material of the object I want it to fade out, so I animated the material and it works but then it doesn't after I unclick from it. Also, I have noticed the Animator component is getting disabled when I play the animation clip.

Comment: It seems Unity related questions are systematically down voted... not very cool but heh, we are still here ! Have you any script that could interact with the animator ? Does this happens in play mode as well ?

Comment: I have tried to play the clip with the script by accessing the animator and animation components. It plays, the values in material component change in the inspector, but it doesn't change anything visibly for the clones that instantiate in Scene.

Comment: The disabling of the Animator afaik is something that the Animation window does automatically when you play the clip there, at least I think I have seen that before. Does the object fade correctly if you change the albedo color by hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by changing to mode to Fade. I don't know why but it was suppose to change itself in the animation but it doesn't.